# Make me a trust

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning, articles, grammaticality-in-context

Is it possible to say in this way, implying trust in something or someone, at the same time using the article?
As from the lyrics of the song Imagine Dragons "Make me A believer."

Grammarly suggests deleting an article because it does not have a plural, but Oxforddictionaries explains that:

LITERARY

a person or duty for which one has responsibility.

plural noun: trusts
"rulership is a trust from God"

> Made me ***a*** trust.

Comment: Why do you think “made me a believer”, that is, turned me into someone who believes, has something to do with “made me a trust” but not in the sense of turned me into someone who is a person you have a responsibility for? Would “made me a truster” make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Make *somebody* *something*" has two quite different meanings:

1. Create the something for the somebody (eg "Make me a sandwich")
2. Cause the somebody to become the something (eg "Make me a tennis-player").

Very occasionally there could be ambiguity between these, but in most cases the meaning is clear depending on whether the "something" is something that a person could be or not.

*Make me a believer* is clearly the second.

But *make me a trust* must be the first, because "a trust" is not something a person can be. (In fact, the only common meanings of "a trust" are legal constructs. When I hear "Make me a trust", I understand it to mean "Create a legal construct called a 'trust' for my benefit).

I think you mean "Make me an object of your trust". In less poetic language, that is equivalent to "Trust me".

Comment: @Colin Fine, but why is not being used "be"? "Make me be a tennis player."

Comment: @Boyep: because we don't have to, and because that would be a different meaning. "Make me be a tennis player" would mean "Force me to be a tennis player" whereas "Make me a tennis player" means "Turn me into a tennis player", or "Help me become a tennis player".

Comment: May be worth noting that "make me a trust" (meaning *make a trust for me*) is much less common than "establish/set up/create a trust."

Comment: @Juhasz so, all the same, does it mean that I can use it this way too?

Comment: @Boyep, if it's clear from the context that you're talking about a legal agreement where one person (the trustee) holds property for a beneficiary, you can say "make me a trust."  But if you do, people will wonder why you didn't say "create/set up/establish a trust for me," since those are all more common.

Comment: @Juhasz: I can imagine a tycoon saying to his lawyer "Make me a trust".